# Normalizing or parsing feature info from GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, getfeatureinfo

I'm building a website to visualize layers from services on an OpenLayers Map.

The services come from different geoservers some of them which I don't own.

All services are WMS and don't have WFS.

I don't know what attributes exist on the layers.

I can only make getfeatureinfo request with text/xml or text/html formats

With this in mind, I'm trying to create a method to show the features info on click but different geoservers send me different results is there a way to ask GeoServer for a default template html?

Or use the readFeatures() from OpenLayers to read the XML returned from a getfeatureinfo request?

I can solve this with C# or JavaScript as I'm able to do some server side coding

Answer (score 1):

The template used for HTML output can only be controlled by the server admin, cannot be passed via the request.

You can however ask for text/xml on all the servers, and then format the result client side in a uniform way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I'm working with geoservers with  different outputs on the text/xml.
One gives back a GML and the other one XML, I would prefer to have all as XML as the xml is easier to parse and doesn't bring coordinates which I'm not interested. Is there a way to make the geoserver reply with xml instead of gml?